# Cant call function from worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've found MD5, SHA1, etc.. implementations that I'd like to use in my worksheet:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/String_Hashing_in_VBA

Calling MD5 from the development enviroment works, but from the worksheet
`=MD5(A5;True)` where A5 contains TEST I get a `#REF!` error. The same with `=MD5("TEST";)` and `=MD5("TEST")`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Publish the code in your question and tell us where did you put it (module, behind a worksheet or workbook?)

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is a cell address in Excel. It is column MD and row 5.

SHA1 is also an address, corresponding to column SHA and row 1:

[image]

You cannot use these as a function name. Try to come up with a better name, e.g. `hashMd5` or `hashSha1`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the function name from MD5 to another thing.

```
Public Function BRGMOZ(ByVal sIn As String, Optional bB64 As Boolean = 0) As String
    'Set a reference to mscorlib 4.0 64-bit

    'Test with empty string input:
    'Hex:   d41d8cd98f00...etc
    'Base-64: 1B2M2Y8Asg...etc

    Dim oT As Object, oMD5 As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim bytes() As Byte

    Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set oMD5 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")

    TextToHash = oT.Getbytes_4(sIn)
    bytes = oMD5.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))

    If bB64 = True Then
       BRGMOZ = ConvToBase64String(bytes)
    Else
       BRGMOZ = ConvToHexString(bytes)
    End If

    Set oT = Nothing
    Set oMD5 = Nothing

End Function
```

And also add the reference "mscorelib"

[image]

**EDIT :** Vityata already answered, sorry.